Using identity server 4 , how can I retrieve connect/token data from the conect/token endpoint from a controller and manually pass that back?
I'm currently working with an Angular SPA app.
I'm successfully signing in externally with google, and retrieving the data from the callback from google.
From here I:

Look up the user
If the user doesn't exist, create the user with identity.
Pass back the data that would normally come from connect/token endpoint.

Here is my code:
[HttpPost("ExternalLogin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLogin([FromBody] ExternalAuthDto externalAuth)
{
    var payload = await _jwtHandler.VerifyGoogleToken(externalAuth);
    if (payload == null)
        return BadRequest("Invalid External Authentication.");

    var info = new UserLoginInfo(externalAuth.Provider, payload.Subject, externalAuth.Provider);

    var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey);

    if (user == null)
    {
        user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(payload.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new ApplicationUser { Email = payload.Email, UserName = payload.Email };
            await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);

            //prepare and send an email for the email confirmation

            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Viewer");
            await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
        }
        else
        {
            await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
        }
    }
    var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
    //sign in the local user (not sure if I should sign out the external user - will that cause conflicts?)
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);

    //Pass back info in this format:
    var returndata = new
    {
        access_token = "thetoken.is.here--",
        expires_in = 3600,
        token_type = "Bearer",
        refresh_token = "refreshtokengoeshere",
        scope = "email offline_access openid phone profile quickapp_api roles"
    };

    return Ok(returndata);

}

